# One armed main character sci fi/ fantasy

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember a series of books I started reading a few years ago I never finished but can only remember a few sketchy details. 
Main character is humanoid with one arm lost one but has incredible rate of healing and pain tolerance. Starts with him as some sort of legionnaire on a desert planet. Winds up being taken prisoner by opposing force and taken to an ice planet. Has some sort of light saver aswell and is talked into working as a merc of some description from then on. Details get hazy but would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Sounds like [Star Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars)

Answer (score 6):

Could be "Death's Head" by David Gunn. Its the first book in a trilogy.

1. Death's Head (2007)
2. Maximum Offense (2008)
3. Day of the Damned (2009)

At the top of the galactic pecking order is the United Free, a civilization of awe-inspiring technological prowess so far in advance of other space-faring powers as to seem untouchable gods. Most of the known universe has fallen under their inscrutable sway. The rest is squabbled over by two empires: one ruled with an iron fist by OctoV, a tyrant who appears to his followers as a teenage boy but is in reality something very different, the other administered by the Uplifted, bizarre machinelike intelligences, and their no-longer-quite-human servants, cyborgs known as the Enlightened.

Sven Tveskoeg, an ex-sergeant demoted for insubordination and sentenced to death, is a vicious killer with a stubborn streak of loyalty. Sven possesses a fierce if untutored intelligence and a genetic makeup that is 98.2 percent human and 1.8 percent . . . something else. Perhaps that “something else” explains how quickly he heals from even the worst injuries or how he can communicate telepathically with the ferox, fearsome alien savages whose natural fighting abilities regularly outperform the advanced technology of their human enemies. Perhaps it is these unique abilities that bring Sven to the attention of OctoV.

Drafted into the Death's Head, the elite enforcers of OctoV's imperial will, Sven is given a new lease on life. Armed with a SIG diabolo - an intelligent gun - and an illegal symbiont called a kyp, Sven is sent to a faraway planet, the latest battleground between the Uplifted and OctoV. There he finds himself in the midst of a military disaster, one that will take all his courage - and all his firepower - to survive.

But an even deadlier struggle is taking place, a struggle that will draw the attention of the United Free. Sven knows he is a pawn, and pawns have a bad habit of being sacrificed.

But Sven is nobody's sacrifice. And even a pawn can checkmate a king.

http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/g/david-gunn/

Comment: Regardless of whether this answers the OP, I'm checking this out! It sounds awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The One Armed Mercenary bit matches "Bill the Galatic Hero" by Harry Harrison.

It was the highest honor to defend the Empire against the dreaded Chingers, an enemy race of seven-foot-tall lizards. But Bill, a Technical Fertilizer Operator from a planet of farmers, wasn't interested in honor-he was only interested in two things: his chosen career, and the shapely curves of Inga-Maria Calyphigia. Then a recruiting robot shanghaied him with knockout drops, and he came to in deep space, aboard the Empire warship Christine Keeler. And from there, things got even worse... From the sweltering fuse room aboard the Keeler, where he loses an arm while blasting a Chinger spaceship, to the Department of Sanitation far below the world-city of Helior, where he finds peace, job security, and unlimited trash...here is Bill, a pure-hearted fool fighting a deluxe cast of robots, androids, and aliens in a never-ending losing battle to preserve his humanity while upholding the glory of the Empire.

Comment: You have to love the "Bloater Drive"

Answer (score -2):

I think you're looking for the Piers Anthony series *Bio of a Space Tyrant*:

1. *Refugee*
2. *Mercenary*
3. *Politician*
4. *Executive*
5. *Statesman*